# Static Object (Item 4 in Effective C++ 3rd Edition)

Tags: c++

In item 4 (page 30/31 in Effective C++ 3rd Ed. ) the following Code example is provided:

Translation Unit 1:

```
class FileSystem {
public:
    ...
    std::size_t numDisks() const;
    ...
};

extern FileSystem tfs;
```

Translation Unit 2:

```
class Directory {
public:
    Directory( params );
    ...
};

Directory::Directory( params )
{
    ...
    std::size_t disks = tfs.numDisks();
    ...
}

Directory tempDir( params );
```

Now Meyers refers to `tempDir` as static object. (page 31, 2nd paragraph)

> But `tfs` and `tempDir` were created by
>   different people at different times in different source files — they’re
>   non-local static objects defined in different translation units.

Well obviously `tfs` is static because it was declared with extern, but why the hack should `tempDir` be static?

Answer (score 4):

`static` has (too) many meanings in C++. Here it means that `tempDir` is defined in the static data area, outside of any functions.

It is not dynamically allocated and it is not a local automatic storage variable.